# How can I get the names of parent headings in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a document:

```
Heading 1
    Heading 2
        Heading 3
          Body Text
```

How can I, in the body text, get the names of each of the parent, grandparent (etc) heading to form a sentence like this:

```
Section 1: Heading 1 -> Heading 2 -> Heading 3
```

I'm comfortable using macros,fields and the like, if that's what's required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for the section:

1. Set your cursor at the point you want to insert your text. Type the word "Section" and add a space.
2. Bring up the `Field` dialog (try `Alt,N,Q,F`; or from the Insert tab, in the Text group, click on Quick Parts and select "Field").
3. From the `Categories:` dropdown, select "Numbering".
4. Select "Section" from the `Field names:` dropdown.
5. From the `Format:` dropdown in the top-middle of the dialog, select "1, 2, 3, ..."
6. Click the `OK` button. It adds the section number.
7. Add your colon and space.

Follow these steps for each heading:

1. Bring up the `Field` dialog per the previous steps.
2. In `Categories:`, select "Links and References".
3. In `Field names:`, Select "StyleRef".
4. From the `Style name:` dropdown in the top-middle of the dialog, select the desired style (starting with "Heading 1").
5. Click the `OK` button. It adds the text of the selected Heading style.
6. Add your arrow.
7. Repeat these steps for the other two headings.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the following field codes set up like this:

Section 1: {styleref "heading 1"} -> {styleref "heading 2"} -> {styleref "heading 3"}

The style reference code will always pick up the last instance of when the style was used.  To insert the field codes, select ctl + F9.  After you insert the code, click on each one and select F9.  You can copy and paste that in for each section in your report.